# Dry Run fails for test using @setup to iterate over JSON in examples

Tags: karate

```
Feature: Feature Name

Background: Background

Scenario1:
     * print ("Scenario1")

    @setup
Scenario: Read JSON file
    * def Idlist = read('classpath:jsonfilepath/list.json')

Scenario Outline:  GET Subgraph version info for <Subgraph>
    Given path '/endpoint/' + '<Id>'
    When method Get
    Then status 200
    
Examples:
    | karate.setup().Idlist |
```

I am using Dry Run options for some reporting using this command-

```
mvn test -Dtest=RunnerName '-Dkarate.options=-D'
```

However, this command fails to return the accurate count where JSON/CSV is being read as a setup scenario with this error-

```
result is neither list nor function: [type: NULL, value: null]
classpath:featurefilepath/featurefiletests.feature:52
```

All such scenario are returned as failed with count as 1 per scenario Outline.

As a workaround, i am running the tests to get the counts. But wanted to check if anyone else has encountered this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a bug where `@setup` is not compatible with the dry-run mode. It will need code changes on the Karate side.

Opened an issue to investigate: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2384